# How to declare a Closure to be used as a function parameter

Tags: grails, groovy, closures

I need to append a new URL mapping on demand and the appender method requires the mapping as a `Closure` (instead of a `UrlMapping` object). Here is what the Closure would look if declared manually:

```
static mappings = {
    name logout: "/auth/logout"{
        action="signOut"
        controller="auth"
    }
}
```

So I declared a `Closure` (which I don't know if it is the correct syntax):

```
String name = "logout", url = "/auth/logout",
    action = "signOut", controller = "auth"

Closure mapping = { name "${name}" : "${url}" {
        action="${action}"
        controller="${controller}"
    }
}
```

And use it to the appender method:

```
Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext
    .getBean("grailsUrlMappingsHolder").addMappings(mapping)
```

But it throws the following error:

> ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application:
>   No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types:
>    (java.util.LinkedHashMap)
>   values: [hapumTransactionAppointmentvacancyTagcandidate:/hapum/transactionappointmentvacancytagcandidate]]
>
> Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), any(groovy.lang.Closure), take(int), each(groovy.lang.Closure)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if understood you correctly but seems that you need something like that:

```
String name = "logout", action = "signOut", controller = "auth"
Closure mapping = { "/${name}"(controller: controller, action: action) }
```

Comment: I'm implementing this right now, although the `name "${name}": ` part is missing.